# Can a simple undirected graph with 11 vertices and 53 edges have a Eulerian circuit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have gathered these but I can't connect them properly.
The sum of the degrees of the vertices is 106.
So d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7+d8+d9+d10+d11=106
To have a eulerian circuit no vertex must have an odd degree.
A complete graph of 11 vertices has 55 edges.

Comment: Is it possible to make all the vertices of $K_{11}$ have even degree by deleting just two edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$K_{11}$ has $55$ edges and all of its edges have even degree. If you remove exactly two edges one vertex will see its degree reduced by exactly $1$.(there are only two cases to consider).